# Play framework 2.0 evolutions and create trigger

Tags: playframework-2.0

I have been trying to get this trigger created using Play 2.0.3.  It runs perfectly fine in MySQL if I run it manually, but it fails when trying to run it from Play.

```
delimiter |
    create trigger company_updated before update on company
        for each row begin
            set new.updated = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
        end;
    |
delimiter ;
```

The error it throws is this:

We got the following error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delimiter | create trigger company_updated before update on company for each row' at line 1 [ERROR:1064, SQLSTATE:42000], while trying to run this SQL script:

Comment: This appears to be a bug...  It's one of several that have me wondering if Play 2 is really production-ready.  https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/212-evolutions-break-on-semicolons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `delimiter` keyword is not a SQL statement, it is only used in the mysql command line client.

Try to remove the `delimiter` parts:

```
create trigger company_updated before update on company
    for each row begin
        set new.updated = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
    end;
```

But as you mentioned, you may hit a [Play bug with the semi-colon](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/212-evolutions-break-on-semicolons) :(

Answer (score 6):

This used to be a bug, and has been fixed in 2.1.
You can use double semicolons to escape. It's documented here:  http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/Evolutions

So your code should be changed as below:

```
create trigger company_updated before update on company
    for each row begin
        set new.updated = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a limitation that we can't really work around.  So, we are currently just not supporting triggers in our app.  Instead, we are just overriding the save/update methods of our models...

```
@Override
public void save() {
    this.updated = new Date();
    this.created = this.updated;
    super.save();
}

@Override
public void update() {
    this.updated = new Date();
    super.update();
}
```

Comment: Another way of creating a trigger should be in the Global.onStart() method with some JDBC connection: first check if the trigger already exists, if not, create it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a delimiter statement. Play will split your file into several query, one file being ended by a ";" character.

If you want to create a complex trigger, you doesn't want play to split your file after a semi colon, so you escape it with a double semicolon ";;".

You end each query with one semicolon and inside a trigger you end your query with a double semicolon.

Example :

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS invoice_line_insert;
CREATE TRIGGER invoice_line_insert AFTER INSERT
ON invoice_line FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.type = "DELIVERY" THEN
        UPDATE invoice
        SET invoice.etdelivery_amount = invoice.etdelivery_amount + NEW.amount
        WHERE invoice.id_invoice = NEW.invoice_parent_id_invoice;;
    ELSE
        UPDATE invoice
        SET invoice.etexpense_amount = invoice.etexpense_amount + NEW.amount
        WHERE invoice.id_invoice = NEW.invoice_parent_id_invoice;;
    END IF;;
    UPDATE invoice
    SET invoice.vatamount = (NEW.amount * (
                SELECT vat.rate
                FROM vat
                WHERE vat.id_vat = NEW.vat_id_vat
    )) + invoice.vatamount
    WHERE invoice.id_invoice = NEW.invoice_parent_id_invoice;;
    UPDATE invoice
    SET invoice.itamount = invoice.vatamount +
            invoice.etdelivery_amount +
            invoice.etexpense_amount
    WHERE invoice.id_invoice = NEW.invoice_parent_id_invoice;;
END;
```