# MySQL stored function with Ebean in Play Framework error

Tags: mysql, playframework, ebean

**What's the problem when using mysql function query with ebean?**

mysql function with Ebean in Play Framework.

-mysql version: 5.5.25a(jdbc:5.1.29)

-play version: 2.3.4

-config ebean in play

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://ip:3306/db?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
db.default.user="id"
db.default.password="pass"
db.default.logStatements=true
evolutionplugin=disabled
```

-mysql function

```
CREATE FUNCTION `get_next_seq_val`() RETURNS BIGINT(20)
BEGIN

    DECLARE reslutval BIGINT;
    SET reslutval := 0;   

    UPDATE t_mas_seq 
         SET last_cached_val = last_cached_val+1
     WHERE seq_nm = 'p_seq_nm';

    SELECT last_cached_val INTO reslutval FROM t_mas_seq
    WHERE seq_nm = 'p_seq_nm';

    RETURN reslutval;

END$$
```

-java src ebean in play

```
int n = Ebean.createSqlQuery("SELECT get_next_seq_val() seq").findUnique().getInteger("seq");
```

**always 'int n' is same number.**

Answer (score 0):

Ebean will split your file each time there is a semi colon, so that there is no need to separate query by anything else than a simple semi colon.
To prevent ebean to split your function's code every time there is a semi colon inside, you must escape semi colon by a double semi colon :

```
CREATE FUNCTION `get_next_seq_val`() RETURNS BIGINT(20)
BEGIN

    DECLARE reslutval BIGINT;;
    SET reslutval := 0;;

    UPDATE t_mas_seq 
         SET last_cached_val = last_cached_val+1
     WHERE seq_nm = 'p_seq_nm';;

    SELECT last_cached_val INTO reslutval FROM t_mas_seq
    WHERE seq_nm = 'p_seq_nm';;

    RETURN reslutval;;

END;
```

See also : [MySQL delimiter statement error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25604055/mysql-delimiter-statement-error)